# Sending Group Text Messages in Our Enterprise from Whatsapp Business Account

Tags: java, facebook, spring-boot, whatsapp, whatsapi

I'm **sending** messages as **individual/group**, but the are identified by Whatapp Business Account Entrprise as but how are identified enterprise as group/**individual**, and I'm trying to figure out why.

This is the facebook for developers pages documenting [Sending Group Messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/group)

Here's an example of sending a message

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/messages type -post
```

Request :

```
{
  "to": "{{Recipient-WA-ID}}",
  "type": "text",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "text": {
    "body": "I am Akash"
  }
}
```

The API properly returns an ID for the message, but how can distinguish whether this message was sent from an individual Person versus a Whats-app group?

When I send a message as an individual person, the API response ID for the message seems to arrive the same was as if it was sent from a group. How can I figure out if it is from a group of the Enterprise (example clients include SBI Bank, JP Morgan, U.S. Bankcorp, etc...)

Comment: Could you please edit your question and rephrase this line 'I have sending message individual/group but how are identified enterprise which are came message from group/individual'? Couldn't understand your question.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I'm still not understand your question; You are posting a message using the Whatsapp API, then the API returns an id for the message that you have sent. What do you want to do now with that id?

Comment: Api return an ID for the message right

Comment: Api return an ID for the message right but how can identify this ID came from individual Person or Whats-app group  <-- this is my question .......   When I send a message in individual person then API response ID for the message right same scenario when a message in group(can have multiple participant in a group) then how will Enterprise identify which person send message in group.
which person are sending message in group 
how will enterprise identify which person is sending message in group?????